# Ranorex build fails 9.4.1 The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found

Tags: c#, automation, .net-framework-version, ranorex

Getting Error  with

```
The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. (MSB3644) - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:1179,5
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework do you use in your projects? Check under Tools > Project upgrade. Then check if the appropriate version of .NET Framework is installed on your machine. It also might help to install the VS Build Tools for the used version of .NET framework. Check [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for installing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by downgraded to 4.6.2 from 4.7.2 under Project > Project Option > Compiling Tab downgraded Target >  .Net Framework

[image]